# Update Query Using strcmp result

Tags: mysql

I am unsure how to change a select query to an update.

The select query is:

```
SELECT IF (strcmp( `player1`, `player2` ) >0, concat(player2, " - ", player1), pair) as GoodPair from scores
```

The problem I am trying to solve is that the pairs field now contains pair names that are not in the same order.  For example "Bill - Dennis" and "Dennis - Bill" for the same pair appear in different records and I want the pair names to be always with the "lesser" name first so that I can count the times that a particular duo is found.

If more info is needed, let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Bili

Comment: do you need to update a new field, or do you want to switch player1 and player2 in case player2 is lesser than player2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LEAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) and [GREATEST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) functions:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT_WS(' - ', LEAST(payer1,player2), GREATEST(player1,player2)) as GoodPair
FROM
  scores
```

I also prefer to use [CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) to concatenate strings with a separator instead of CONCAT but in this particular case it is the same.

To create an update query, I would use this:

```
UPDATE scores
SET
  GoodPair = CONCAT_WS(' - ', LEAST(payer1,player2), GREATEST(player1,player2))
```

If you just need do swith player1 with player2 in case that player1 is greater than player2, you could use this UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE score
SET player1=LEAST(player1,player2),
    player2=GREATEST(player1,player2)
WHERE
  player1>player2
```

Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b182/1).

Comment: Thanks, obviously I need to study the language more.  I didn't know about the least and greatest functions.